# Image tagging solution for files on external hard drive on windows/linux dual boot pc?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, linux-mint, image-editing

I have a Windows 10/Linux Mint 17.3 dual boot PC with an NTFS formatted external hard drive. I have a lot of image files (probably a few GBs) on the external HD I use for art reference (mostly png, jpeg, gifs, but also few MangaStudio, GIMP, and Photoshop).

I want to organize all my art reference with tags, so I could (for example) search for "hands" and see all images focused on hand gestures. I search for "hands" and "women" together to see all pictures of women's hands.

However, I want to be able to use the same tag database in both Windows & Linux partition (or at least keep in it sync some how).

What are my options? I would prefer a free solution (an open-source solution would be even better). I'm pretty privacy minded, so I would also prefer a solution that doesn't upload all stuff to the cloud. Being able to export and load separate databases of tags would also be good.

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0):

You could try TagSpaces. It tags more than just photos, but I think it would be perfect for what you're trying to do with it.

Self Hosted, Open Source, Supports Mac, Windows, Linux, Android, and iOS

http://www.tagspaces.org/

Comment: unfortunately, this renames the files (no sidecar support) so its utility is limited in e.g. linked file situations such as Graphic Design. I can see some issues with filename length issues and valid file naming conventions also, but these are probably less significant a problem. Might also "clutter" searches in file managers with limited query filtering support?

Comment: **(From the FAQ) Where does TagSpaces save the tags?**

Currently the tags are added in name of the file, so for example if you tag the file “img-9832.jpg” with the tags “sunset” and “bahamas” it will be renamed to “img-9832 [sunset bahamas].jpg”. A version of TagSpaces which saves the tags in a sidecar files will be released soon.

Comment: It is interesting, and I use filenames as "metadata" for music files, but for a large professional-ish library the filename length can get up there very quickly. Certainly fits the need as asked though.

Answer (score 0):

I also find that tags don't work in external drives.

My solution is to tag the relevant word(s) in the file name.

Additionally, I find that you can extend the length of the file name (from the limits set by the external or internal drives), by opening the file in a graphics editor software called "Irfan View."

I hope that helps.